# ionic 3 on ionic run removes my custom fonts

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I upgraded lately to ionic 3, in my new project i use custom font when i use `ionic serve` it copy the fonts from `src/assets/fonts` to `www/assets` and it works well.

But when i run it on android using `ionic cordova run android` the font files inside `www/assets` disappears and it run on my device with no fonts.

my ionic info:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v6.10.3
npm               : 3.10.10
OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: Please check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810684/fonts-not-getting-applied-on-android-device-in-ionic-3-app).

Comment: Hi man, have you found a solution to this? Having the same problem here...I'll do some research and if I find anything I'll let you know.

Comment: i will let you know too

Comment: @sebaferreras i do like the answer say, but it is not right why should i copy the fonts every time i run on my device?

Answer (score 2):

It is something weird with the latest version of ionic cli 3.9.2 or webpack (not sure). **Fonts with WOFF extensions only are copied**

I tried using WOFF format instead of TTF and it works.

Comment: this seems to be true

Comment: my fonts must be ttf , so i need a solution.

Comment: This solves the problem for me. I used an online converter. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be placing the asset into your WWW folder before the build. 
if you add a fonts folder to your www it should place it in your platforms when you add the platforms and emulate, if not you will need to add the font to your platforms folder for it to emulate and be in your builds

yourapp/platforms/android(or ios)/assets/www/font

Answer (score 0):

try running `ionic cordova build android` before running `ionic cordova run android`.

Comment: Doing that didn't worked for me at least. For me it seems like a bug. When I run either of those commands, I can observe in the `assets/fonts/` folder the fonts are being added for a few seconds, but after webpack starts, a few seconds later the fonts are removed.